# How to Calculate Win Percentage In Pandas Library?

Tags: python, pandas, average, mean, percentage

HomeTeamName   AwayTeamName   HomeTeamGoals AwayTeamGoals
0   France        Mexico        4.0          1.0
1   USA         Belgium         3.0          0.0
2   Yugoslavia  Brazil          2.0          1.0
3   Romania     Peru            3.0          1.0
4   Argentina   France          1.0          0.0

Comment: This shows very little work and no question text at all. I would suggest you rewrite it in a question (not just in the title) and show what you have done until now, otherwise you probably get a lot of downvotes. Also read the how to post a question on this site.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A Percentage is calculated by the mathematical formula of dividing the value by the sum of all the values and then multiplying the sum by 100. This is also applicable in Pandas Dataframes. Here, the pre-defined sum() method of pandas series is used to compute the sum of all the values of a column.

Syntax: Series.sum()

Return: Returns the sum of the values.

Formula:

df[percent] = (df['column_name'] / df['column_name'].sum()) * 100
for example
# Import required libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
# Dictionary
df1 = {
 'Name': ['abc', 'bcd', 'cde',
         'def', 'efg', 'fgh',
         'ghi'],
 'Math_score': [52, 87, 49,
               74, 28, 59,
               48]}

 # Create a DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, 
               columns = ['Name',
                         'Math_score'])

# Calculating Percentage
df1['percent'] = (df1['Math_score'] / 
              df1['Math_score'].sum()) * 100

# Show the dataframe
df1
```